# How to trigger javascript on another webpage by only using it's link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

The title is probably a bit unclear, i'll try to explain the question with an example.

At http://imgur.com there is an upload button for uploading images. When it is clicked, the url does not change. Instead, a pop-up appears, and it is triggered from javascript. Now, what if I wanted to give a link for the webpage that automatically opens the pop-up on default, without having the user click the upload button.

This is a bit tricky because the url for the homepage/upload page is the exact same, but one of them is a pop-up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If what you're asking for was possible, I'd be able to construct a link that does this: `http://yourbank.com/[some code that listens for your username and password and sends it to me so that I may steal all of your money]`, thankfully it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to invoke a script on another website, and for good reason. Do some research into "cross site scripting" for an in depth explanation.

There is however, an [Imgur API](http://api.imgur.com/) available to you if you want to hook into the website's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Didn't click that the target wasn't under your control sorry, this answer is irrelevant for your specific question, but I'll leave it incase it it helpful to someone who also mis-interprets your question and arrives via search.

**Original Answer:**

You can use the `hash` portion of the URL to trigger the popup:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#new') {
    window.location.hash = '';

    $('#create-link').trigger('click');
}
```

We use this to trigger the create dialog when you go to 'http://mysite.com/item/**#new**'